# How to join several matrices with different shapes into one diagonal matrix and pad 0 for off diagonal elements?

Tags: python, matrix

If I have these matrices:

```py
A = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]   
B = [[0,0],[1,1]]
C = [[0,1,1],[1,1,0],[1,0,1],[0,0,0]]
```

how can I combine them to get a matrix like this?

```py
[[1. 2. 3. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [4. 5. 6. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [7. 8. 9. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

I am looking for a general solution that is not limited to let's say only 3 input matrices.

Comment: Please define "join" and "diagonal" in your context.

Comment: The example given is self explanatory. A,B, and C are input matrices and output is `D = [A00 0B0 00C]` with A,B,C elements appearing in diagonal of D and off diagonal elements are 0. Are you looking for a mathematical description for "join" or "diagonal"?

Answer (score 1):

Solely as an academic exercise....

```
A = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]   
B = [[0,0],[1,1]]
C = [[0,1,1],[1,1,0],[1,0,1],[0,0,0]]

data = [A,B,C] # merge for iteration

rowlen = sum(len(x[0]) for x in data)  # full row length

mtx = []

col = 0
for d in data: # each data list (A/B/C)
   for d2 in d:  # each sublist
      mtx.append([0]*col + d2 + [0]*(rowlen-col-len(d2))) # data plus '0' buffers
   col += len(d[0])  # shift column 

print(mtx)
```

Output

```
[[1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [4, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [7, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to avoid using `for` loops to gain speed?

Comment: List comprehension would be difficult to implement here and any speed gain would be minimal.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that it could be simply done with `block_diag` from scipy:

```py
from scipy.linalg import block_diag
data = [A,B,C]
block_diag(*data)
```

output:

```
array([[1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [4, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [7, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```